# Ways to reduce the overhead of multiple configuration and Persistence Contexts to use similar operations on all databases under a single structure?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jpa, deltaspike

So I was wondering how following problem would be solved best in a JPA/JavaEE enviroment:

Imagine you have multiple stores, each equipped with a separate database (but the same domain structure). Every night all databases are going to be interrogated by a main HQ Server and some calculations are done.

In my opinion, the best solution would be:

- Timer which schedules the interrogation.
- Multiple DataSources for each store
- Maybe some producers (for each store one) to use deltaspike data.

Is there a way to reduce the overhead of multiple configuration and PersistenceContexts to use the same operations on all databases? Like some sort of strategy pattern for JPA?

Comment: ([**Multi-tenancy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) might be the search key you are looking for.)

Comment: All i find are references on multi-tenancy for single databases, but in my scenario there are multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this post [Multi-tenancy](http://lambda-et-al.eu/multi-tenancy-with-jee-and-jboss/) I helped me solve it.